# jqplot not displaying in jquery page

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, jqplot

I am using jqmobile pages to switch between the pages of an html5 app. One page includes a jqplot chart.

Here is my code:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page-two" data-title="Page 2">
            <div id="chart1" style="height:100%;width:100%;"></div>
        </div>




// javascript
$(document).delegate("#page-two", "pageshow", function() {

                             var plot2 = $.jqplot ('chart1', [[3,7,9,1,4,6,8,2,5]], {
                                                   // Give the plot a title.
                                                   title: 'Plot With Options',

                                                   axesDefaults: {
                                                   labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer
                                                   },

                                                   axes: {
                                                   xaxis: {
                                                   label: "X Axis",

                                                   pad: 0
                                                   },
                                                   yaxis: {
                                                   label: "Y Axis"
                                                   }
                                                   }
                                                   });
                             });
```

It looks like the chart is kind of rendering...here's a picture of the page[image]

The chart has correct data inputs, as it worked when I tested it on another page. I cannot change the height or width of that empty space either from the height and width attributes on the chart itself. I have all of the correct javascript files too.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: If the height and width of the parent container with `id="page-two"` has a height and width of 0, then the child container will have a height and width of 0 even with the `height:100%` and `width:100%` rules.

Comment: The parent is the body, it has a width and height of 100%

Comment: I believe I poorly worded my first comment. The container of `chart1` is `page-two`. If `page-two` does not have height or if it does not have width then neither will `chart1`. So if `page-two` does not have `height:100%` defined (in order to inherit from the body) it will have a `height=0` and that will cascade to the chart.

Comment: hmm...I tried that but it still does not seem to be working? I even put a div around the chart with height and width attributes but still no luck. Thanks for the response though, i'll keep working at it

Comment: I actually just tried deleting the chart and the screen has the same appearance. I'm not sure what that line in the middle is but it appears the chart isn't working at all :/

Comment: Delegate is deprecated. Perhaps you should try using `on` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have jqplot.canvasAxisLabelRenderer.min.js included.

Comment: yep, that's included. The code works in a different app. The problem happens when I try to put the chart in a jqmobile page

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem...It looks like it was a dumb error on my part.

The Jquery .js files must come BEFORE the jqplot .js file in the header!